# Modx дерево детей

Tags: modx

Здравствуйте, Уважаемые!

Необходимо понять, как решить проблему. У меня стоит задача сделать сайт, на котором есть список категорий, из этого списка я попадаю на страничку, где показывается блог по 1 посту. Каждый пост является предком ещё нескольких. Привожу пример, как это выглядит для пользователя:

Человек заходит на сайт, видит список категорий. Заходит, например, на первую и видит одну большую новость и рядом с ней список мелких новостей, которые к ней относятся. Под большой новостью есть пагинация, при переходе на другую страницу, меняется главная новость и её под новости соответственно. Пока что вывожу вот так:

```
[!Ditto? &tpl=`ditto_collection` &sortBy=`createdon` &summarize=`1` &paginate=1!]
```

Выводятся только главные новости.

За любые советы или помощь буду очень благодарен. В тупике уже 2-й день.

Comment: да, но как выводить и то и другое на одной странице?

Comment: чёт я на метку не обратил внимание, на ответ моё решение не тянет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас есть Id родительской новости. Можно вытянуть всех дочерних вот так:

```
$news = $modx->getDocumentChildren(
$id = $ваш_id,
$active = 1, 
$deleted = 0
);
```

Потом отображать список дочерних новостей в виде кратких аннотаций :

```
foreach($news as $key => $value)
{
echo '<div class="header"><a href="'.$value["alias"].'">'.$value["pagetitle"].'</a></div>';
echo '<div class="annotacia">'.$value["introtext"].'</div>';
}
```

Comment: хотелось бы сделать всё через ditt. Т.к. нужна пагинация

Comment: Честно говоря, стараюсь использовать относительно самописные решения, без готовых сниппетов

Answer (score 2):

В чанке ditto_collection, где выводится новость, в блоке где у тебя подновости выови еще раз сниппет Ditto, только уже так

```
[!Ditto? &tpl=`ditto_subnews` &sortBy=`createdon` startID=`[+id+]` &paginate=1!]
```

где [+id+] получается id текущей новости, т.е. текущая папка с которой выводить подновости, соответственно для главной новости должны быть созданы дочерние документы - подновости.